# Merging arrays to a single array to find minimum value

Tags: php, arrays, explode, minimum

I have a csv file and I am trying to get  the minimum value for a particular column. However I am not getting an exact value even after exploding  the values. After I explode and I do a var_dump on it, it produces a different array for each different row; so each value in the column is the first element of a different array. How do I merge this different arrays into one array in order to find the minimum value in the column, or is there any other way to go about it? Below is my code. Any help will be appreciated.

merging

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== false) {              

            $table2Add =false;
            if($row >=$x && $row <=$y) {
                $table2Add=true; }


                if($row == 1) {
                    $table2 .= '<thead><tr>';                       
                    $table2 .= '<th></th>';
                    $table2 .= '<th>Min</th>';
                    $table2 .= '<th>Max</th>';
                    $table2 .= '<th>Average</th>';
                    $table2 .= '</tr></thead><tbody>';


                }
                else {

                    if($table2Add) $table2 .= '<tr><th>Voltage</th>';
                    for($c = 0; $c <= 10; $c++) {
                        $value = empty($data[$c]) ? "&nbsp;" : $data[$c];

                            if($c==1) {
                                var_dump((explode('STRING',$data[$c])));
                                //$ar=explode('STRING', $data[$c]);

                                //var_dump(min($ar));

                                if ($table2Add) $table2 .='<td>'.round($value,2).'</td>';
                            }       
                            if($c==2) {
                                if ($table2Add) $table2 .='<td>'.round($value,2).'</td>';
                            }
                            if($c==3) {
                                if ($table2Add) $table2 .='<td>'.round($value,2).'</td>';
                            }
                    }

                    if($table2Add) $table2 .= '</tr>';



                    if($table2Add) $table2 .= '<tr><th>Current</th>';
                    for($c = 0; $c <= 10; $c++) {
                        $value = empty($data[$c]) ? "&nbsp;" : $data[$c];
                        if($c==4) {
                            if ($table2Add) $table2 .='<td>'.round($value,2).'</td>';
                        }
                        if($c==5) {
                            if ($table2Add) $table2 .='<td>'.round($value,2).'</td>';
                        }
                        if($c==6) {
                            if ($table2Add) $table2 .='<td>'.round($value,2).'</td>';
                        }
                    }

                    if($table2Add) $table2 .= '</tr>';


                    if($table2Add) $table2 .= '<tr><th>Power Factor</th>';
                    for($c = 0; $c <= 10; $c++) {
                        $value = empty($data[$c]) ? "&nbsp;" : $data[$c];
                        if($c==7) {
                            if ($table2Add) $table2 .='<td>'.round($value,2).'</td>';
                        }
                        if($c==8) {
                            if ($table2Add) $table2 .='<td>'.round($value,2).'</td>';
                        }
                        if($c==9) {
                            if ($table2Add) $table2 .='<td>'.round($value,2).'</td>';
                        }
                    }

                    if($table2Add) $table2 .= '</tr>';



                }
                $row++;
        }
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your data? A few rows of your CSV?

Comment: Here's a link to the actual file. Many Thanks https://www.dropbox.com/s/n7pyv96qv1yv8yc/Example%20SG%20Data.xlsx

Comment: I'll look at it later today.

Comment: Where is your definition of `$table2`, `$x`, `$y`, and `$row`? What do they mean? You need to edit your code with more comments so we know what you're trying to do. Also, you should always use `{ }` with control flow statements.

Comment: $table2 is a table, $x and $y are just values 3599 and 36000. $row initialised to 0 to check the number of rows in the file. There are 3600 row. Thanks will do that more often

Comment: Well add a bunch of comments, add in the declarations of those variables, and then edit that code into your question. Otherwise, it's too vague for anyone to help you.